# Problemas con una consulta y con switch

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero hacer una consulta contra una tabla de la siguiente forma:

Primero obtengo los nombres de los campos donde quiero buscar siendo el valor de **$campo** el nombre de los campos de la tabla

```
for($i=1;$i<9;$i++){  

    $agrupacion=substr($subcta,-8,$i);
    $longitud=strlen($agrupacion);
    switch($longitud){
        case 1:
            $campo='grupo';
            break;
        case 2:
            $campo='subgrupo';
            break;
        case 3:
            $campo='cuenta';
            break;
        case 4:
            $campo='agrupacion';
            break;
        case 8:
            $campo='subcuenta';
            break;
        default:
            $campo="definicion";
            break;
    }
```

Aquí y, según mi planteamiento ,dependiendo de la longitud del elemento, buscará en un campo o en otro:

```
//confirmamos la existencia de la agrupacion en la tabla subcuentas
    $subcuenta = Subcuenta::where("'$campo'",'=', $agrupacion )
                                        ->where( 'id','<>',$datos['id'] )
                                        ->where( 'suscriptor_id','=', $datos['idsusc'] )
                                        ->first();
```

Y es donde se produce el fallo, ya que no entiende "**'campo'**" y da el siguiente mensaje de error:

> local.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''grupo'' in 'where clause'

Espero haberme explicado, gracias anticipadas.

Si en la petición quito las comillas de '**"$campo"**' y dejo sólo la variable
**$campo** queda de la siguiente forma:

```
$subcuenta = Subcuenta::where($campo,'=', $agrupacion )
                                        ->where( 'id','<>',$datos['id'] )
                                        ->where( 'suscriptor_id','=', $datos['idsusc'] )
                                        ->first();
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

> observe que en SUBCUENTA RESULTANTE DE LA PETICION no aparece ningún valor, el 1 corresponde al valor false al no existir

```
[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: agrupacion obtenida con substr               1                       longitud                    1  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: campo obtenido con switch                           
                          grupo  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: subcuenta resultante de la peticion                                                           
                        1  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: agrupacion obtenida con substr               10                       longitud                    2  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: campo obtenido con switch                           subgrupo  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: subcuenta resultante de la peticion                                                           1  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: agrupacion obtenida con substr               100                       longitud                    3  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: campo obtenido con switch                           cuenta  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: subcuenta resultante de la peticion                                                           1  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: agrupacion obtenida con substr               1000                       longitud                    4  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: campo obtenido con switch                           agrupacion  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: subcuenta resultante de la peticion                                                           1  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: agrupacion obtenida con substr               100000                       longitud                    6  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: campo obtenido con switch                           definicion  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: subcuenta resultante de la peticion                                                           1  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: agrupacion obtenida con substr               10000000                       longitud                    8  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: campo obtenido con switch                           subcuenta  

[2020-05-29 11:39:46] local.INFO: subcuenta resultante de la peticion                                                           1
```

Comment: quitale la comillas simple y doble: `"'$campo'"`... así: `where($campo,'=', $agrupacion )`

Comment: No devuelve nada,te envío el resultado obtenido:

Comment: A la atención de black sheep:No devuelve nada ,añado a la pregunta en resultado de la petición  dejando  $campo

Comment: al menos ya no tienes el error :) ... el resto es problema de tu logica del código...

Comment: Que orm estás usando? Lo digo porque normalmente después de un where se suele añadir un "andWhere"...

Comment: Por eso he dicho antes que tienes que comprobar tu lógica de código... es decir.. comprueba las variables que recibes en el `switch`... y así sucesivamente hasta que encuentres el fallo...

Comment: Estoy utilizando laravel y php contra una base de datos mysql

Comment: Para Black sheep:Perdona la tardanza, Tenías toda la razón en la lógica de la consulta

Comment: A la atencíón de Jakala: La lógica de la consulta era incorrecta